# On events? Turn it off?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On keyup my script does something, I was wondering if I could turn it off, as in, I only want it to check one key up.

```
ckEditorNewsArticle.document.on("keyup", function(){
```

Edit:

```
ckEditorNewsArticle.document.on('keyup', function(){
                      alert('key up');
                });
```

This works. But I cant get it to fire only once, by using one.

```
ckEditorNewsArticle.document.one('keyup', function(){
                      alert('one');
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off events using (surprise, surprise), `.off()`.

```
ckEditorNewsArticle.document.off('keyup');
```

If you want a handler to run only once though, might I suggest using `.one()`?

```
ckEditorNewsArticle.document.one('keyup', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: It might not be, but it should. Can you update your question with the code using `.one()` that isn't working?

Comment: and what is `ckEditorNewsArticle.document`?

Answer (score 3):

use `.one()`:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most once per element.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/54ymc/

Comment: I'm not familiar with ckeditor, but did you verify that your `ckEditorNewsArticle.document` element is a jquery element? maybe you should try `$(ckEditorNewsArticle.document)`.